# python parse xml website with urllib

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have to get all the "activities" from this website which is in XML: 
http://www.bcn.cat/tercerlloc/agenda_cultural.xml

In order to do so I created this classes whose will keep the new activities from the XML:

```
class GeoLoc(object):
    def __init__(self, adresa, lat, lon):
        self.adresa = adresa
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon

    def valid(self):
        return self.lat !="" and self.lon != ""


class Acte(GeoLoc):
    nom = ""
    def __init__(self, line):
        super(Acte, self).__init__(line[0], line[1], line[2])
        self.nom = line[3]
```

the thing is I don't know how to get this value for example:

```
<row num="9" pos="8">
```

(the value of the row num and pos) and also how to get to this address

```
<address label="Adreça">
<![CDATA[Pl Glòries Catalanes 37
```

I would like to have something like this (I'm using it for a different xml):

```
    sock = urllib.request.urlopen("http://wservice.viabicing.cat/getstations.php?v=1")
    xmlSource = sock.read()
    sock.close()
    root = ET.fromstring(xmlSource)
    estaciones = []
    #obtenemos las estaciones de bicing 
    for element in root.findall('station'):
        elements = []
        if (element.find('streetNumber').text != None):
            elements.append(element.find('street').text + " - " + element.find('streetNumber').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse XML with parameter: `strip_cdata=False` to keep CDATA, accessing tag attributes can be done using `.attrib` property. Please review the lxml [docs/tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
root = etree.XML(sock, parser)

for element in root.findall('.//row'):
    addr = element.find('.//address')
    if addr is not None:
        print element.attrib            
        print addr.text
        print ""
```

Comment: I just changed findall('row') by your ('.//row') and it worked, why is that?